# How to do RPM build from 3 Sources

Tags: build, rpm

I want to create RPM build from 3 sources: tomcat, java, and some war file.
I need to do RPM file that is possible to install without any coonection by runing it on any Centos linux system.
Please help to do this. I already read a lot of links and guides but can't do that till end. I already make some .spec file but it have misstakes.
For understanding the question: I'm making this first time. The **main task** is to build RPM that will install Tomcat, Java and pull my *.war to Tomcat.
Maybe someone can help from 0?
I have make some .spec file but it seems to me that is wrong way.
Please help me with some guide step by step or something like that.

```
Summary: File system 
Name: test 
Version: 1.0.0 
Release: 1%{?dist}
Group: Applications/File 
License: GPLv2+ 
Url: http://Softserve.com.ua
Source0: java-1.7.0-openjdk-src-1.7.0.131-2.6.9.0.el7_3.x86_64.tar.gz
Source1: tomcat-8.0.41-1.fc26.src.tar.gz 
Source2: OMS.tar.gz
BuildRoot: %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{version}-%{release}-root-%(%{__id_u}-n)

%description Test1 

%prep

#Source0 %setup -q -c -b0 
#Source1 %setup -q -c -b1 
#Source 2 %setup -q -c -b2

%build make CFLAGS="$RPM_OPT_FLAGS" "CPPFLAGS=$(getconf LFS_CFLAGS)"
%{?_smp_mflags}

%install mkdir -p "$RPM_BUILD_ROOT" cp -R * "$RPM_BUILD_ROOT" rm -rf
$RPM_BUILD_ROOT mkdir -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{_bindir}

#make   make%{?_smp_mflags}
#       BINDIR=$RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{_bindir} \
#       MANDIR=$RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{_mandir}/man1 \ install chmod -x    $RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{_mandir}/

%clean rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT

%files %defattr(-,root,root)
##%{_bindir}/tree
##%{_mandir}/man1/tree.1* %doc README LICENSE

%changelog
* Wed Mar  3 2017
```

Comment: Can you check the edit looks ok. Please post what errors are you getting ?

Comment: As noted above, post your errors. Also, why are you building Java and Tomcat? Do you just want an RPM-based copy of your WAR and then just `Require` the standard Java / Tomcat?

Comment: yes, i need java-1.7.0-openjdk and Tomcat, then pull my war file for deploing to ~tomcat/webapps/

Comment: + make 'CFLAGS=-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic' CPPFLAGS=
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.pKbSQQ (%build)